# I need to sum the columns by a particular condition and display in the row as total using exceljs nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, exceljs

[Here is my excel file I generated using exceljs.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZrw4.png)I need to add the weight for every grnNo and display the result as a total at the end of that particular grnNo,[Something like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqZTo.png)

Here is my code

```
  var userss = inward.aggregate([{
                $match: {
                    $and: [
                        { "defaultAccountId": { "$gte": parseInt(userParam.defaultAccountId), "$lte": parseInt(userParam.defaultAccountId) } },
                    ],
                    $or: [{ "createdDate": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end } }]
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: "$fabricArray"
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    grnNo: "$grnNo",
                    grnDate: "$grnDate",
                    party: "$party",
                    orderNo: "$orderNo",
                    lotNo: "$lotNo",
                    buyer: "$buyer",
                    vehicleNo: "$vehicleNo",
                    dyeingName: "$dyeingName",
                    dyeingDcNo: "$dyeingDcNo",
                    partyDcNo: "$partyDcNo",
                    weight: "$weight",
                    fabricName: "$fabricArray.fabricName",
                    fabricColor: "$fabricArray.color",
                    fabricDia: "$fabricArray.dia",
                    fabricRolls: "$fabricArray.rolls",
                    fabricTotalKgs: "$fabricArray.totalKgs",
                    fabricRemarks: "$fabricArray.remarks",
                    color: "$color",
                    fabricCondition: "$fabricCondition",
                    partyDcRolls: "$partyDcRolls"
                }
            }


        ], function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            }

            var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
            var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Inwards')
            worksheet.columns = [
                { key: "grnNo", header: "GRN_No" },
                { key: "grnDate", header: "Date" },
                { key: "party", header: "Party" },
                { key: "orderNo", header: "OrderNo" },
                { key: "lotNo", header: "LotNo" },
                { key: "buyer", header: "Buyer" },
                { key: "vehicleNo", header: "VehicleNo" },
                { key: "dyeingName", header: "dyeingName" },
                { key: "dyeingDcNo", header: "DyeingDcNo" },
                { key: "partyDcNo", header: "PartyDcNo" },
                { key: "color", header: "Color" },
                { key: "fabricCondition", header: "Fabric_Condition" },
                { key: "partyDcRolls", header: "PartyDcRolls" },
                { key: "weight", header: "Weight" },
                { key: "fabricName", header: "Fabric_Name" },
                { key: "fabricColor", header: "Fabric_Color" },
                { key: "fabricDia", header: "Fabric_Dia" },
                { key: "fabricRolls", header: "Fabric_Rolls" },
                { key: "fabricTotalKgs", header: "Total_Kgs" },
                { key: "fabricRemarks", header: "Remarks" },

            ]

            worksheet.getCell('A1').font = {
                bold: true
            };
            worksheet.getCell('B1').font = {
                bold: true
            };
            worksheet.getCell('C1').font = {
                bold: true
            };
            worksheet.getCell('D1').font = {
                bold: true
            };
            worksheet.getCell('E1').font = {
                bold: true
            };

            worksheet.getCell('F1').font = {
                bold: true
            };

            worksheet.getCell('G1').font = {
                bold: true
            };
            worksheet.getCell('H1').font = {
                bold: true
            };
            worksheet.getCell('I1').font = {
                bold: true
            };
            worksheet.getCell('J1').font = {
                bold: true
            };

            worksheet.getCell('K1').font = {
                bold: true
            };
            worksheet.getCell('L1').font = {
                bold: true
            };
            worksheet.getCell('M1').font = {
                bold: true
            };
            worksheet.getCell('N1').font = {
                bold: true
            };
            worksheet.getCell('O1').font = {
                bold: true
            };
            worksheet.getCell('P1').font = {
                bold: true
            };
            worksheet.getCell('Q1').font = {
                bold: true
            };
            worksheet.getCell('R1').font = {
                bold: true
            };
            worksheet.getCell('S1').font = {
                bold: true
            };
            worksheet.getCell('T1').font = {
                bold: true
            };

            worksheet.getCell('U1').value = { formula: 'N2+N5', result: undefined };

            result.forEach(function(row, rows) {
                worksheet.addRow(row);
            })

            workbook.xlsx.writeFile(filePath)
                .then(function() {
                    console.log("excel file created successfully");
                });

        }).allowDiskUse(true);
        return await (userss)

    }
```

I am a total beginner, any idea how to do it?. I don't know whether to calculate my expected total values while fetching data's from the database or is there any function that can do this task in exceljs itself. Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, hope it will help someone. I didn't get my expected result by using exceljs, so I just switched to excel4node. Here I calculated the value and inserted into the cell

```
 async function getInwards(userParam) {
        const dateTime = new Date().toISOString().slice(-24).replace(/\D/g,
            '').slice(0, 14);
        const filePath = "Inwards" + dateTime + ".xlsx";
        const start = new Date(userParam.fromDate);
        const end = new Date(userParam.toDate);
        var wb = new xl.Workbook();
        var ws = wb.addWorksheet('Inwards')
        if (userParam.fromDate && userParam.toDate) {
            var inw = await inward.find({
                defaultAccountId: { "$gte": parseInt(userParam.defaultAccountId), "$lte": parseInt(userParam.defaultAccountId) },
                createdDate: { "$gte": start, "$lte": end }
            })

            var style = wb.createStyle({
                font: {
                    bold: true

                },
                numberFormat: '$#,##0.00; ($#,##0.00); -',
            });
            ws.cell(1, 1)
                .string('GrnNo')
                .style(style);

            ws.cell(1, 2)
                .string('GrnDate')
                .style(style);

            ws.cell(1, 3)
                .string('Party')
                .style(style);

            ws.cell(1, 4)
                .string('OrderNo')
                .style(style);

            ws.cell(1, 5)
                .string('LotNo')
                .style(style);

            ws.cell(1, 6)
                .string('Buyer')
                .style(style);

            ws.cell(1, 7)
                .string('VehicleNo')
                .style(style);

            ws.cell(1, 8)
                .string('DyeingName')
                .style(style);

            ws.cell(1, 9)
                .string('DyeingDcNo')
                .style(style);

            ws.cell(1, 10)
                .string('PartyDcNo')
                .style(style);

            ws.cell(1, 11)
                .string('Color')
                .style(style);

            ws.cell(1, 12)
                .string('FabricCondition')
                .style(style);

            ws.cell(1, 13)
                .string('PartyDcRolls')
                .style(style);

            ws.cell(1, 14)
                .string('Weight')
                .style(style);

            ws.cell(1, 15)
                .string('FabricName')
                .style(style);

            ws.cell(1, 16)
                .string('FabricColor')
                .style(style);

            ws.cell(1, 17)
                .string('FabricDia')
                .style(style);
            ws.cell(1, 18)
                .string('FabricRolls')
                .style(style);

            ws.cell(1, 19)
                .string('TotalKgs')
                .style(style);

            ws.cell(1, 20)
                .string('Remarks')
                .style(style);


            const n = inw.length

            var count = 0;
            for (a = 0; a < n; a++) {
                const nn = inw[a].fabricArray
                const nnn = nn.length
                var addrolls = 0;
                var addtotal = 0;

                ws.cell(a + 2 + count, 1)
                    .string(inw[a].grnNo)

                ws.cell(a + 2 + count, 2)
                    .date(inw[a].grnDate)

                ws.cell(a + 2 + count, 3)
                    .string(inw[a].party)

                ws.cell(a + 2 + count, 4)
                    .string(inw[a].orderNo)

                ws.cell(a + 2 + count, 5)
                    .string(inw[a].lotNo)

                ws.cell(a + 2 + count, 6)
                    .string(inw[a].buyer)

                ws.cell(a + 2 + count, 7)
                    .string(inw[a].vehicleNo)

                ws.cell(a + 2 + count, 8)
                    .string(inw[a].dyeingName)

                ws.cell(a + 2 + count, 9)
                    .string(inw[a].dyeingDcNo)

                ws.cell(a + 2 + count, 10)
                    .string(inw[a].partyDcNo)

                ws.cell(a + 2 + count, 11)
                    .string(inw[a].color)

                ws.cell(a + 2 + count, 12)
                    .string(inw[a].fabricCondition)

                ws.cell(a + 2 + count, 13)
                    .number(inw[a].partyDcRolls.value)

                ws.cell(a + 2 + count, 14)
                    .number(inw[a].weight.value)
                for (i = 0; i < nnn; i++) {
                    ws.cell(a + 2 + count, 15)
                        .string(inw[a].fabricArray[i].fabricName)

                    ws.cell(a + 2 + count, 16)
                        .string(inw[a].fabricArray[i].color)

                    ws.cell(a + 2 + count, 17)
                        .string(inw[a].fabricArray[i].dia)

                    ws.cell(a + 2 + count, 18)
                        .number(inw[a].fabricArray[i].rolls.value)

                    ws.cell(a + 2 + count, 19)
                        .number(inw[a].fabricArray[i].totalKgs.value)

                    ws.cell(a + 2 + count, 20)
                        .string(inw[a].fabricArray[i].remarks)
                    count = count + 1
                    addrolls = addrolls + inw[a].fabricArray[i].rolls.value
                    addtotal = addtotal + inw[a].fabricArray[i].totalKgs.value
                }

                ws.cell(a + count + 2, 17)
                    .string('Total')
                    .style(style);

                ws.cell(a + count + 2, 18)
                    .number(addrolls)

                ws.cell(a + count + 2, 19)

                .number(addtotal)



            }
            wb.write(filePath, function(err, stats) {

                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    return err
                }
            });



            if (inw) {

                return await (inw)
            }
        }

    }
```